# This Python code basically prompts the user to type their valid phone number and tries to produces equivalent word for each digit in phone number

Tags: python

The compiler is spitting out KeyError: '9' when run. Can someone help me out in omitting the said error from this code? Thanks in advance!

```
phone = input("Phone: ")
if len(phone) < 10:
    print("Phone number should be at least 10 digit long!")
else:
    li = []
    for item in range(0, 10, 1):
        li.append(phone[item])
print(li)
word_num = {
     0: "Zero",
     1: "One",
     2: "Two",
     3: "Three",
     4: "Four",
     5: "Five",
     6: "Six",
     7: "Seven",
     8: "Eight",
     9: "Nine"
}
for item in li:
    print(word_num[int(item)])
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your last for loop, first fix that

Comment: Also you can do `for char in phone: li.append(char)` for better readability.

Comment: It's because `"9"` is not the same as `9`. The former is str, the latter int. Your dictionary contains int type keys, not str. Use the `int()` function to convert each item from str to int, and then look it up in the dictionary.

Comment: I did that but the error persists.

Comment: Hi! I converted the 'item' to int and it runs without problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Because the characters from the phone number are strings, the dictionary keys must be strings:

```py
word_num = {
     "0": "Zero",
     "1": "One",
     "2": "Two",
     "3": "Three",
     "4": "Four",
     "5": "Five",
     "6": "Six",
     "7": "Seven",
     "8": "Eight",
     "9": "Nine"
}
```

There are also other issues in your code. The last for loop should be:

```py
for item in li:
    print(word_num[item])
```

Moreover, you need to stop code execution if the the phone number length is less than 10, otherwise the program will try to print `li` that does not exist yet.

Comment: Well, dictionary keys don't *have* to be strings, they just need to be in this case, since the values he's using to index the dictionary are strings. Dictionary keys just have to be a hash-able object.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I was obviously referring to this particular case.

Comment: No worries, I understand, that's why I didn't downvote your answer or edit it. But I did want the OP to be aware since *he* might not realize that.

Answer (score 1):

The `word_num` has keys as `int`, but you are trying to access them as `word_num['0']` instead of `word_num[0]`. Moreover, the last `for` loop should be:

```
for item in li:
```

The `for` loop `for item in range(0, 10, 1):` can be rewritten as:

```
for item in range(10):
```

### Corrected Code

```
phone = input("Phone: ")
if len(phone) < 10:
    print("Phone number should be at least 10 digit long!")
else:
    li = []
    for item in range(10):
        li.append(phone[item])
    print(li)
    word_num = {
        0: "Zero",
        1: "One",
        2: "Two",
        3: "Three",
        4: "Four",
        5: "Five",
        6: "Six",
        7: "Seven",
        8: "Eight",
        9: "Nine"
    }
    for item in li:
        print(word_num[int(item)])  # convert item to int
```

---

### Sample Output

```
Phone: 0123456789 
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Zero
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
Seven
Eight
Nine
```

EDIT 1: If input is less than 10 characters, then do nothing.

Comment: You need to stop code execution if the length is less than 10, otherwise the program will try to print `li` that does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few issues with your code. You need to ensure that every character entered as part of `phone` is actually a digit. And then you must convert the string value to an int before you can use it to index `word_num`. Finally, if the user enters something fewer than 10 characters, you fall through with `li` being uninitialized.

```py
import re

while True:
    phone = input("Phone: ")
    if len(phone) >= 10 and re.fullmatch(r'[0-9]+', phone):
        break
    print("Phone number should be at least 10 digit long!")

li = [int(d) for d in phone]
print(li)
word_num = {
     0: "Zero",
     1: "One",
     2: "Two",
     3: "Three",
     4: "Four",
     5: "Five",
     6: "Six",
     7: "Seven",
     8: "Eight",
     9: "Nine"
}
for item in li:
    print(word_num[item])
```

Sample run:

```None
Phone: aaa
Phone number should be at least 10 digit long!
Phone: a012349499595
Phone number should be at least 10 digit long!
Phone: 1234567890
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
Seven
Eight
Nine
Zero
```

Answer (score 0):

if you define "li" at the start of the program then it works just fine.
I was unable to paste the code so here is a link
[001.py](https://replit.com/@40476/python#001.py)

Answer (score -1):

You need to rewrite last for loop like that

```
for item in li:
    print(word_num[item])
```

Comment: Presumablyly the OP made this syntax error while uploading their code, which your code does fix. But it doesn't fix their actual error, which was a `KeyError`.

Comment: The error he is having is key error, which isn't solved by this